# Error does not occur in VS2010 when debugging but does occur if I run the program outside VS2010 from the debug folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a C# app which has an error which I cannot locate.

When I run the app from within the debugger, the error does not occur but if I run the app from outside VS2010 in the debug folder (still the debug version of the app) I get the error.

The error is an 'Object not set to an instance of an object'. The error itself is not the issue itself, but why it doesn't happen when debugging in VS2010 (.NET 4).

Comment: What error? where do you see it?? can be so many things, that is hard to tell...

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: It crashes out, whats the error when it crashes?

Comment: @JonSkeet: That should be required reading.

Comment: If you add an event handler to `AppDomain.UnhandledException`, you should be able to capture the exception object and log the exception stack trace to a file.

Comment: I already do that. I know what the error is, I know where it happens but I cannot breakpoint anywhere to find the cause because the error does not occur when debugging within the VS debugger.

Comment: probably because your engine is loading something, that when you run the exe by itself is not loaded.. a dll???

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the exception and the relevant portion of the code where the exception occurs?  Also, have you tried attaching the debugger to the running instance instead of running it through Visual Studio?

Comment: No I haven't tried that. I will give that a try first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know where the error occurs then simply write a one-liner before it to start the debugger:

```
   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```